# Java DecimalFormat HALF_UP format double value is not correct

Tags: java, decimalformat

The DeciamlFormat with **RoundingMode.HALF_UP** is **not working correctly with double value**.

```
double value = 2.315;
double value2 = 2.325;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

System.out.println("double value1 = " + value);
System.out.println("double value2 = " + value2);
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(df.getRoundingMode() + " value = " + df.format(value));
System.out.println(df.getRoundingMode() + " value2 = " + df.format(value2));
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(df.getRoundingMode() + " value = " + df.format(value));
System.out.println(df.getRoundingMode() + " value2 = " + df.format(value2));
```

The code above generate the result below, **HALF_UP 2.315d result as same as HALF_EVEN.**

```
double value1 = 2.315
double value2 = 2.325
HALF_UP value = 2.31  // Why the result is not 2.32?
HALF_UP value2 = 2.33
HALF_EVEN value = 2.31
HALF_EVEN value2 = 2.33
```

But DeciamlFormat with RoundingMode.HALF_UP format **"2.315 float value "** will be **the correct value 2.32.**

 I work with JDK 1.8.0_131 version.

Comment: Probably because the values shown aren’t the real values of the floating point numbers? There isn’t an exact representation for a lot of these values.

Comment: Exactly. Try printing them with no rounding at all and a few more zeroes and you will see what they really are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I change to this code java.lang.Math.round( value * 100d ) / 100d;

Comment: Well, I see. should not even use java.lang.Math.round to do the round half up.

Comment: The multiply/divide trick doesn't actually work except in a few corner cases.